# Cannot able to emit Array of WritableMap from android to react-native

Tags: android, react-native, eventemitter

I have object like the below

```
 data class CallInfo (

@SerializedName("callStatus") val callStatus : String,
@SerializedName("callType") val callType : String,
@SerializedName("callDirection")val callDirection: String,
@SerializedName("callMode") val callMode : String,
@SerializedName("users") val users : List<Users>
)
```

And i'm trying to send this object to react-native by Emit method

```
@ReactModule(name = RoomModule.NAME)
public class RoomModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule  {

public static final String NAME = "RoomModule";

public RoomModule(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
}

   public static void startCall(){

    Random random = new Random();
    String randomString = String.valueOf(random.nextInt()).replace("-", "");

    ArrayList<Users> usersArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    usersArrayList.add(new Users("Thiyaga1","https://thiyagadude.com/api/v1/media/xSoIkb0XAh1590760167030"));
    usersArrayList.add(new Users("Thiyaga2","https://thiyagadude.com/api/v1/media/xSoIkb0XAh1590760167030"));
    CallInfo callInfo=new CallInfo("calling","audio","outgoing","onetoone",usersArrayList);

    @Nullable Bundle launchOptions = ConstructBundle.INSTANCE.getCallUsersJsonObject(callInfo);
    WritableMap initialProps = Arguments.makeNativeMap(launchOptions);
    WritableNativeMap appParams = new WritableNativeMap();
    appParams.putMap("initialProps", initialProps);
   

    ReactInstanceManagerHolder.emitEvent("com.thiyaga.react:features/connection_service#startCall",appParams);
}
}
```

ConstructBundle.kt

```
 Object ConstructBundle{
   private fun getCallUsersJsonObject(userInfo:CallInfo):Bundle? {

    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("id", userInfo.id)
    bundle.putString("name", userInfo.name)
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("users", getUsersObject(userInfo.users) )
    return bundle;
}
private fun getUsersObject(users: List<Users>): ArrayList<Bundle> {

    val array = ArrayList<Bundle>()
    for (user in users) {
        val jo = Bundle()
        jo.putString("name", user.name)
        jo.putString("avatar", user.avatar)
       array.add(jo)
    }
    return array
}
}
```

i should be getting the map as the below..

```
 {"initialProps": { "callStatus": "calling","callDirection": "outgoing","callType": "audio", "callMode": "onetoone", "users": [
    {
      "name": "Thiyaga1",
      "avatar": "https://thiyagadude.com/api/v1/media/xSoIkb0XAh1590760167030"
    },
    {
      "name": "Thiyaga2",
      "avatar": "https://thiyagadude.com/api/v1/media/xSoIkb0XAh1590760167030
    }
  ]
}}
```

but instead i'm getting like the below

```
 {"initialProps": { 
"callStatus": "calling",
"callDirection": "outgoing",
"callType": "audio", 
"callMode": "onetoone", 
"users": [[Object], [Object]]
}}
```

the issue here is that if i send the  data without assigning to "initialProps" key value i could able to send the whole data...

```
{ "callStatus": "calling","callDirection": "outgoing","callType": "audio", "callMode": "onetoone", "users": [
    {
      "name": "Thiyaga1",
      "avatar": "https://thiyagadude.com/api/v1/media/xSoIkb0XAh1590760167030"
    },
    {
      "name": "Thiyaga2",
      "avatar": "https://thiyagadude.com/api/v1/media/xSoIkb0XAh1590760167030
    }
  ]
}
```

thank in advance for everyone who is answering.. hope community helps me from my nightmare..

Comment: You should use promise instead of returning an array from Android native method to React native as every @react method should have void return type so your method  getUsersObject should return void and should have a promise param which will act as call back

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be like below

```
public void getUsersObject(Promise promise) {
   promise.resolve(your_array);

}
```

then use it in React Native code as callback from this function

Comment: The React isn't accessing the any of the above methods.. android native alone send a data to the react-native through the emit event.